# Propagate the default_library option through subprojects

Tags: meson-build

I want to build a project which has subprojects, which in turn have their own subprojects. And I want all of them to be statically linked. With the direct dependencies it's simple

```py
my_dep = dependency('my', fallback('my','my_dep'),
                          default_options: ['default_library=static'])
                          # or static: true, same resut
```

But this only works for the dependency itself, all the other subprojects that are needed by that dependency are still dynamic. Right now I use a hacky solution by patching all the meson files inside of all the subprojects to use something like

```
- second_dep = dependency('second', fallback: ['second', 'second_dep'])
+ second_dep = dependency('second', fallback: ['second', 'second_dep'],
+                                   default_options: ['default_library=' + get_option('default_library')])
```

But I wonder if there is a proper way to propagate `default_library` through all the subprojects.